# How to calcualte the average of several plaintexts with Paillier homomorphic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I am trying to do some calculations with the Paillier Homomorphic encryption scheme. Specifically, given three plain text integers, `x1, x2,`and `x3`. I want to first encrypt them, getting their corresponding ciphertexts, say `c1, c2` and `c3`. I want to find the results of `(x1+x2+x3)/3` by utilizing `c1, c2, c3` and the homomorphic property of Paillier.

I found a post [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53257/paillier-homomorphic-encryption-to-calculate-the-means/53311#53311?newreg=7b0e5fda167e43e78ac8422c4e0bc335), which was answered quite a long time ago. When I try the toy example in the accepted answer in this link myself, I can not get the provided result. Specifically, for the following step:[image]

I can calculate the value of `k^(-1) mod N` with `powermod` function correctly, but I can not calculate `[\mu]` correctly. Here is what I did:

1. Say `temp = powermod(k, -1, N)`, Calculate `A = powermod(c1*c2*c3, temp, N^2)`.
2. Calculate `B = powermod(r, N, N^2)`.
3. Calculate `[\mu] = mod(A*B, N^2)`.

This gives me wrong results, I also try replacing `powermod` with `mod`, but this time the answer is going to NaN.

Can anyone help me with this, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure precisely which language you're using, but the intermediate values should be

`temp=206674`

`A=284095452063`

`B=144829438301`

and the calculation works fien for me.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment! I am using matlab with powermod function, the value of  `A` is different from the one you have (`B` is the same), any ideas? (I can confirm when I call the function, the values of `c1, c2` and `c3` are correct and I have `319242668083` for `A`)

Comment: ... and your value for `temp` is?

Comment: Value of `temp` is also the same as the one you show...

Comment: aha, I tried this computation with Python, and now everything is fine. But do you have any idea why the value of `A` is the only one that is not correct when using Matlab? I do not think the reason is the number precision...

Answer (score 0):

Mathlab is not directly adequate for the large integers used in public-key crypto.

Reading The [Fine Manual](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html) shows there is a limit of $2^{64}$. Even $c_1\cdot c_2$ exceeds that.

Python, SageMath, Mathematica, and many other languages have no such limitation. That makes them adequate for experimenting with the math in public-key crypto (but *not* necessarily implementation of public-key crypto when it comes to adequate speed, or resisting side-channel attacks).