# homomorphic division with scaling/Paillier

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

Let's say that I have to use fractions instead of integers and I am using Paillier cryptosystem. So, I use scaling to obtain integers. Assume that I have a secure division protocol. What happens if the result of the division is not an integer?

Scenario:

The scaling factor is 10.

- $x = E(10)$ // encryption of 1
- $y = E(3)$ // encryption of 0.3
- $z = E(10/3)$ // with a secure division protocol

Let's say that I choose parameters accordingly and 3 has inverse. Then, when I multiply 10 with 3 inverse homomorphically (interactive multiplication), I will see something different than 3.3. I cannot get this problem solved on my mind.

Comment: You need the inverse of 3 to multiply. So the result is $E(10 \cdot 3^{-1})$

Comment: It is important to note that due to the properties of the Paillier system and the parameters selected at the time the keys are created, 3 may not have a modular multiplicative inverse in the group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division in paillier cryptosystem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/division-in-paillier-cryptosystem), if this is not solving your question let us know.

Comment: Edited accordingly. This is not solving my question.

Comment: The accepted answer says that: If $D\nmid M$ ($D$ does not divide $M$), even if the $gcd=1$, the result will not necessarily make sense.